# how do i change background image of list items on select?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, onchange

so i have a 3 step list items.

item 1 
item 2
item 3

and i need to have a background image (an arrow) appear on selection of each. If the user clicks item 2, the arrow will disappear from item 1 and appear in item2 etc.

i tried somthing like this but not sure...

```
         <script>
                $(".theSteps li").change(function () {
                $(".theSteps li:selected").each(function () {
                $('.theSteps li').css('background-image','url()');
                });
                $('.theSteps li').css('background-image','none');
                })
                .trigger('change');

            </script>
```

Comment: How exactly do you get that LI element to change and be selected ?

Comment: you have a extra dash in `$('.theSteps li').css('background--image','url()');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've got a working solution here for you. All you need to do is modify the glow class to be a background image (and sort out the positioning etc.)

http://jsfiddle.net/jezzipin/5J698/

As some of the guys above have said in the comments the best way to do this is use a css class which is only active on the element you have just clicked. In my example I call this class glow ->

```
  .glow{
 background-color: #FF0000;   
 }
```

All it will do is change the background colour of an element to red.

Now for the jQuery function (may be different from the fiddle as that calls document.ready() automatically) ->

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
          $('.theSteps').click(function() {
          $('.theSteps').removeClass('glow');
          $(this).addClass('glow');             
   });

   });
```

This function removes the glow class from all elements with the class .theSteps and then applies it to whichever element has just been clicked which we can reference with $(this) .

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided the HTML, so it is quite hard to create the full JavaScript that you will need. If you can add that in, I can give you some more details.

The easiest way to do this is to create a **CSS class** that is used to just set the background image to that of the image that you want to use.

If you run a function when your list item is selected, you can run the jQuery function [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to add your new class to specify the background image to that selected item - something like:

```
$('#mylistitem').addClass('BackgroundImageClassName');
```

Before this line, you can remove the class from any existing items by using:

```
$('li.BackgroundImageClassName').removeClass('BackgroundImageClassName');
```

Assuming your html looks something like:

```
<ul class="theSteps">
  <li>first item</li>
  <li>second item</li>
</ul>
```

You can use a code like this:

```
$('ul.theSteps li').click(function() { 
  $('li.newBackgroundImageClass').removeClass('newBackgroundImageClass');
  $(this).addClass('newBackgroundImageClass');
});
```

Comment: ok thanks, can you give me a working example? html is not needed, im just using list elements displaying inline.
its the jquery/javascript i need.

Comment: I have updated with example HTML and more complete code. I need the html so that I can select the correct items. @user1106295

Comment: and this will take away each image if i click another? e.g so only one image will been seen per click?

Comment: Yes it will. The removeClass will remove it from all other items.

Comment: also the code provided has errors in it :s
       <script> 

    $('ul.theSteps li').click(function() {

        $('li.stepClass').removeClass('stepClass'); 
  $(this).addClass('newstepClass'); 
  
  }

</script>

Comment: Missed out the ); after the } bracket. I will edit above post.